# Erro "Undefined symbols" ao compilar projeto

Tags: c++, osx

Estou tentando compilar um projeto em C++, mas está dando o seguinte erro:

> ```
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
>   "knapSack(int, int*, int*, int)", referenced from:
>
>       _main in main-b722ae.o
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ```

Alguma ideia do que isso pode ser?

Estou usando o sistema MacOs X 10.9. Segue o trecho do código onde está sendo apontado o erro:

```
// Returns the maximum value that can be put in a knapsack of capacity W

int knapSack(int W, int wt[], int val[], int n)
{
   int i, w, profit, cont = 0;

   item* K = NULL;

   //Build table K[][] in bottom up manner

   for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)    
   {    
       for (w = 0; w <= W; w++)   
       {    
           if (i==0 || w==0) 
           {
               profit = 0;

               K = insertItem(profit, K);
           }

           else if (wt[i-1] <= w)
           { 
               profit = max(val[i-1] + returnItem(K, (i-1), (w-wt[i-1]), W),  returnItem(K, (i-1), w, W));

               K = insertItem(profit, K);
           }

           else  
           {
               profit = returnItem(K, (i-1), w, W);

               K = returnItem(profit, K); 
           }

           cont++;

            if(cont % 1000 == 0)
            {

                cout << "i = "<< i << "w = " << w << "profit = " << profit << endl;//printf("i = %d, w = %d, profit = %d \n", i, w, profit);

            }
       }
   } 
   return returnItem(K, (i-1), (w-1), W);
}
```

Comment: Você linkou a lib na hora de compilar? Talvez o link esteja com o caminho errado, presumo que é isto que esta mensagem quer dizer "linker command failed"

Answer (score 1):

O arquivo fonte onde a função "knapSack" foi definida não foi incluído no build.

Ou então, se é uma função fornecida por uma biblioteca, esta biblioteca deve ser fornecida na link-edição.

Como fazer ? Isso depende de como você está trabalhando, se é linha de comando ou se é uma IDE.

Supondo linha de comando e gcc, e supondo que você tem os arquivos knapSack.h e knapSack.cpp com a interface e a implementação da função, então você precisa incluir o arquivo knapSack.cpp na compilação, por exemplo:

```
g++ -o xxx main.cpp knapSack.cpp
```

Comment: Eu declarei a função "knapSack" em um arquivo .h, que é incluído no início do código. Não basta só isso para funcionar, em qualquer caso de chamadas de funções que estejam em outros arquivos?

Comment: Não basta só a  **declaração** uma função ou variável, é necessário também a **definição**. Note que em C++ estes são termos técnicos. Você precisa compilar o arquivo fonte onde a função knapSack está **definida**, e incluir o arquivo objeto (.o ou .obj) gerado na link-edição. Se for uma função fornecida por uma biblioteca, você precisa incluir a biblioteca na link-edição. Como você está compilando ? É na linha de comando ? É com IDE ? Você precisa dar mais informações para ter uma resposta mais específica.

Comment: Eu estou compilando na linha de comando, com o g++. Acho que entendi o que você falou. Consegui incluir os arquivos da maneira correta agora. Mas para ficar claro, eu criei um .h com o protótipo (a declaração, como você disse) da função knapSack e um .cpp para a implementação dela (a definição). Na minha main, que chama a função, eu devo chamar o .cpp?